# Extension of probability on different algebras

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have a probability measure $P$ defined on 2 semi-algebras $S_1$ and $S_2$. According to the first extension theorem, there is a probability measure $P^*$ defined on the smallest algebra that contains S1 and this $P^*$ is unique.

I am just wondering whether $P^*$ is also defined on the smallest algebra that contains $S_2$ (In other words, is $P^*$ an extension of P from $S_2$ to the smallest algebra that contains $S_2$).

Comment: Are you sure this question is stated as intended?  Why isn't it answered simply by exchanging the roles of $S_1$ and $S_2$?  If you intend for this $P^{*}$ to be the same algebra in both cases, then surely you must posit *some* kind of relationship connecting $P^{*}$ with $S_2$, either by constructing $P^{*}$ with respect to $S_2$ in the first place or by assuming some definite relationship between $S_1$ and $S_2$--but none of that is in evidence here.

Comment: Actually I assumed S1 and S2 are independent collections. This does not come from any particular question, I was just curious about a potential finding and want to confirm whether it is true or not